# Unable to build standalone jar using boot

Tags: clojure

**EDIT:** Added more information at the end. Also, got war to run with jetty-runner.jar (not with tomcat however)

I am using [boot](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot) as the build tool for my clojure application.

This is the first application I have written with  `cljs`, `cljc` and `clj` code (along with `sass`) all in one project.

My `build.boot` has the following `task-options`

```clj
(def db-opts (:db (clojure.edn/read-string (slurp "resources/config.edn"))))
(task-options!
 pom {:project 'gcr
      :version "0.1"}
 cljs    {:optimizations :simple}
 uber    {:as-jars true}
 war     {:file "gcr.war"}
 ragtime {:database (str "jdbc:"
                         (:dbtype db-opts) "://"
                         (:user db-opts) ":"
                         (:password db-opts) "@"
                         (:host db-opts) ":"
                         (:port db-opts) "/"
                         (:dbname db-opts))}
 test    {:include #"gcr.test"
          :junit-output-to "junit-out"})
```

my `build` task is defined as follows:

```clj
(deftask build
  "Builds an uberjar of this project that can be run with java -jar"
  []
  (comp
   (aot :all true ;; :namespace #{'gcr.server}
        )
   (pom)
   (cljs :optimizations :simple)
   (sass)
   (uber)
   (jar :file "gcr.jar" :main 'gcr.server)
   (sift :include #{#"gcr.jar"})
   (target)))
```

When i run `boot build` the project builds fine without any errors.

But when I run `java -jar target/gcr.jar`

I get the following:

```
$ java -jar target/gcr.jar
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd -Dswing.aatext=true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: clojure/lang/Var
        at gcr.server.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: clojure.lang.Var
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

I have been looking at this for about 24 hours now and still unable to figure out how to get this working. (I finally was able to build a war that works with `jetty-runner` but not on tomcat)

### ----------

Some more info:

My `boot.properties` is

```
BOOT_CLOJURE_NAME=org.clojure/clojure
BOOT_CLOJURE_VERSION=1.10.0
BOOT_VERSION=2.8.2
```

and I am using `openjdk version "1.8.0_202"`

I checked if the jar file built has the clojure jar using `jar tf target/gcr.jar` and the following line is listed:

```
7c506484bc48541ffa5dcb4d9366a8a2-clojure-1.10.0.jar
```

My IFDE works fine, I have the following `dev` task defined as follows:

```clj
(deftask dev
  "Launch Immediate Feedback Development Environment"
  []
  (comp
   (serve :handler 'gcr.core/app   ;; ring handler
          :resource-root "public"  ;; root classpath
          :reload true)            ;; reload ns
   (watch)
   (reload)
   (cljs-repl) ;; before cljs task
   (cljs)
   (sass)
   (target :dir #{"public"})))
```

`set-env!` part is as follows:

```clj
(set-env!
 :source-paths #{"src/scss" "src/clj" "src/cljs" "src/cljc"}
 :resource-paths #{"html" "resources"}

 :dependencies '[[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.10.520"]
                 ;; server
                 [compojure "1.6.1"]
                 [ring/ring-core "1.7.1"]
                 [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.7.1"]
                 [ring/ring-json "0.4.0"]
                 [ring-middleware-format "0.7.4"]
                 ;; [javax.servlet/servlet-api "2.5" :scope "test"]
                 ;; [yogthos/config "1.1.1"]
                 ;; java 10 upgrade
                 [javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api "2.4.0-b180830.0359"]
                 ;; common
                 [org.clojure/core.async "0.4.490"]
                 [org.clojars.akiel/async-error "0.3"]
                 [hickory "0.7.1"]
                 [instaparse "1.4.10"]
                 ;; clj
                 [clj-time "0.15.1"]
                 [clj-http "3.9.1"]
                 [clout "2.2.1"]
                 [org.clojure/data.json "0.2.6"]
                 [org.clojure/data.codec "0.1.1"] ;; Base64
                 ;; cljs
                 [com.andrewmcveigh/cljs-time "0.5.2"]
                 [prismatic/dommy "1.1.0"]
                 [hipo "0.5.2"]
                 [hodgepodge "0.1.3"]
                 [cljs-http "0.1.46"]
                 [com.cemerick/url "0.1.1"]
                 [reagent "0.8.1"]
                 ;; db
                 [ragtime "0.8.0"]     ;; Migrations
                 [hikari-cp "2.7.1"]   ;; Connection Pooling
                 [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.7.9"]
                 [honeysql "0.9.4"]
                 [org.postgresql/postgresql "42.2.5"]
                 ;; Authentication framework with JWT
                 [buddy/buddy-auth "2.1.0"]
                 [buddy/buddy-core "1.5.0"]
                 [buddy/buddy-sign "3.0.0"]
                 ;; argon2 for password hashing
                 [de.mkammerer/argon2-jvm "2.5"]
                 ;; logging
                 [com.taoensso/timbre "4.10.0"] ;; logging
                 [com.fzakaria/slf4j-timbre "0.3.12"]
                 [org.slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j "1.7.26"]
                 [org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j "1.7.26"]
                 [org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j "1.7.26"]
                 ;; spec , test & gen
                 [org.clojure/test.check "0.9.0"]
                 ;; Dependencies for build process
                 [adzerk/boot-cljs "2.1.5"]
                 [adzerk/boot-test "1.2.0" :scope "test"]
                 [pandeiro/boot-http "0.8.3"]
                 [adzerk/boot-reload "0.6.0"]
                 [adzerk/boot-cljs-repl "0.4.0"]
                 [cider/piggieback "0.3.9" :scope "test"]
                 [nrepl "0.4.5" :scope "test"]
                 ;; [com.cemerick/piggieback "0.2.2" :scope "test"]
                 [weasel "0.7.0" :scope "test"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.13" :scope "test"]
                 [mbuczko/boot-ragtime "0.3.1"]
                 [deraen/boot-sass "0.3.1"]
                 [tolitius/boot-check "0.1.12"]])
```

After a lot of playing around with tasks, I was able to build a war file that works with `jetty-runner` with the following task:

```clj
(deftask build-war
  "Build the target/app.war file"
  []
  (comp
   (aot :all true)
   (web :serve 'gcr.core/app)
   (cljs :optimizations :advanced)
   (sass)
   (sift :move {#"(.*)js$" "public/$1js"
                #"(.*)html$" "public/$1html"
                #"css/(.*)" "public/css/$1"})
   (uber)
   (war :file "gcr.war")
   (sift :include [#"gcr.war"])
   (target)))
```

Using the `sift` task to move the static resources to the `public` folder was key, since I had my compojure resources defined as follows in my `routes.clj` (not including API and other routes).

```clj
(defroutes gen-routes 
  (GET "/login" [] auth/auth-handler)
  (files "/" {:root "public"})          ;; to serve static resources
  (resources "/" {:root "public"})      ;; to serve anything else
  (not-found "404 Page Not Found"))     ;; page not found
```

This however still does not produce a `war` file that works on tomcat. That is, on deploying to tomcat, all the API routes works as expected, but the static html files come up as HTTP/404.

Comment: Please post your environment configuration for boot. ie `(set-env! ...)` This is probably an issues with your dependencies.

Comment: Not a boot user here, but have you checked the directory your .jar ends up in, has more than one jar?  Some tooling keeps both the original jar (just your code) and the fatjar side by side with different names.

Comment: @flyboarder added more of build.boot

Comment: @cfrick boot doesn't do this. I also double checked I didn't miss a separate fatjar in the target folder :(

Comment: @pvik this should work without issues. If it runs under jetty then I would suggest this is a tomcat specific issue.